# How to LabelEncode only particular columns of the dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Suppose I have a dataset like this now I want to encode only a particular columns which have string value. Like in below mentioned array I want to LabelEncode only a[0][0] , a[0][1], a[0][3] , a[0][4].

> a = [[Andaman and Nicobar Islands, NICOBARS, 2000, Kharif, Arecanut, 1254.0, 2000.0]]

What I have tried is :

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('crop_production.csv')

from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
dataset = dataset.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

But it encodes even numerical values.

Any idea how to encode only a particular columns of csv ?

Dataset sample :

```
State_Name  District_Name   Crop_Year   Season  Crop    Area    Production

Andaman and Nicobar Islands NICOBARS    2000    Kharif      Arecanut    1254.0  2000.0
```

Comment: You want to encode only the 0th, 1st, 3rd and 4th column of your dataframe. Am I right.?

Comment: yes @SreeramTP and also decode it again

Comment: okay. Show the sample of the dataframe with headers

Comment: How is a[0][4] different from a[0][5]. Is it so that 4 is string and 5 not?

Comment: which all columns you want to encode.? Specify the names please

Comment: yes I want only to encode string values @DeepakSaini

Comment: State_Name, District_Name, Season and Crop @SreeramTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a sample data frame as shown below

```
sample = pd.DataFrame()

sample['A'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
sample['B'] = ['x', 'y', 'x', 'z']
sample['C'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sample['D'] = ['m', 'n', 'm', 'o']


# sample dataframe

    A   B   C   D
0   a   x   1   m
1   b   y   2   n
2   c   x   3   m
3   a   z   4   o
```

Here columns A, B and D are containing strings and column C is numerical. So you want to encode A, B and D but not C. To do that you can make a encoder specific to one column and enocde the column as needed. See the below codes for that.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder_A = LabelEncoder()
encoder_B = LabelEncoder()
encoder_D = LabelEncoder()

sample['A'] = encoder_A.fit_transform(sample['A'])
sample['B'] = encoder_B.fit_transform(sample['B'])
sample['D'] = encoder_D.fit_transform(sample['D'])

# encoded dataframe

    A   B   C   D
0   0   0   1   0
1   1   1   2   1
2   2   0   3   0
3   0   2   4   2
```

You can extend this code to your specific problem easily.

Comment: directly in the sense.? Without providin the column names.?

Comment: By providing column name but not creating data frames

Comment: You can use the similar logic. Instead of providing the column name, you can provide the index of the column. since you are already using pandas to read the csv, i dont think that is necessary

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach that you can use without providing (or knowing) column names is this:

```
# seperate categoricals from numericals
df_numeric = dataset.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
df_obj = dataset.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()

# now factorize categoricals
for c in df_obj:
    df_obj[c] = pd.factorize(df_obj[c])[0]

# merge back into one dataframe
df_final = pd.concat([df_numeric, df_obj], axis=1)
df_final.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: But then again if I want to decode it what should I do like I encoded `a` to `1` now I want the corresponding values of `1` , how to achieve that ?